# Steps to add result types to Advanced Search page and successfully get hits

Tags: advanced-search, result-types

I have advanced search working fine for the 4 main result types that are there. How do i have it find txt file types.  I added the new result type to the result type drop down , I see it and i select it but the txt file is not returned when i select search button.  the search is showing its looking for ALL(*)(FileExtension="txt") so that looks right...  any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Oh I think i know the issue.  The query that I have does not include txt files.  I feel stupid.  I will update the query and if it works then I answered my own question.

Answer (score 1):

I had created a result source a while back and i did not include the return of txt file as part of the query.  I just assumed I was returning txt files. Even though I added the result type for txt in the drop down of my advanced search web part I still would not get any hits because the result source query didn't include txt.  All is working now that i updated the result source query that I am using to include txt files.